# Update a partial in dust.js without touching the rest of the template

Tags: javascript, templates, partials, dust.js

I'm experimenting around with dust.js and am wondering about the most efficient way to solve this:

I have a simple template structure with 2 levels of navigation and content.

The first level of navigation is static - while the second level (the subnavigation) changes with each change in the primary navigation.

---

Parent Template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        {>"navigation/navigation_primary"/}
        {>"navigation/navigation_secondary"/}
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Primary Navigation Template:

```
<div class="navbar-container navbar-primary">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {#navigation_primary}
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#{slug}">{label}</a>
        </li>
        {/navigation_primary}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Secondary Navigation Template:

```
<div class="navbar-container navbar-secondary">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {#navigation_secondary}
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#{slug}">{label}</a>
        </li>
        {/navigation_secondary}
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Now, my problem is this: Without reloading the page, I'ld like to update the "secondary navigation", when I click on the primary navigation elements.

The way I'ld do this, is to re-render the "Secondary Navigation Template" and then replace the old ".navbar-secondary" with the newly rendered template ( with jQuery.html() ) - but I was wondering if dust.js has it's own feature for this, since it's able to load partials asynchroneusly?

To be honest, I didn't find most of the dust.js documentation very informative, so I'm having a hard time figuring the details out.

**Is there a better way to update only a partial and leaving the rest of the template untouched, without using something like jQuery.html() and replace the partial in dust.js?**

Comment: Dust is just a string renderer-- it only takes templates in and spits rendered strings out. It has no functionality for placing these strings anywhere in the DOM.

Comment: @Interrobang I guess I'm already using the right method to update partial areas of the template, then.